# Should MVC 2 - Preview release be easily upgraded to Beta when it's released?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Should I just be able to install the beta on top of this without problems when it is released ?

Not sure how it is treated within  the visual studio environment. I'm thinking with it being a type of project in VS it should be ok.

Can anyone clarify?

MVC 2 is looking to be rather good from what I heard from [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/) @ the Manchester conference, can't wait for the final release :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a chance of a breaking change when using preview and beta software.  If you want to use MVC 2 Preview, you need to accept the fact that there might be some work in your future to make your project compatable with the Beta, RC, and then Final releases.  It won't necessarily break, but the earlier in the release schedule (such as a preview instead of a beta) the greater the chances are you'll have to make changes to your code as they move forward.

Comment: what about the install of the package rather than the coding written using it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, they ask you to un-install old previews/betas before installing the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

When MVC 1.0 previews were released, [there were](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/27/asp-net-mvc-preview-3-release.aspx) [breaking changes](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/asp.net-mvc-codeplex-preview-5-released.aspx) between the releases. If you try to keep up with each preview, you should be able to resolve any problems rather quickly - and you could provide great feedback, too!